# Prove that $L_f \vert E$ has degree $2$, or there are exactly three fields satisfying those conditions

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

> Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[t]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ and $L_f \subset \mathbb{C}$ a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that there is no field $E$ with $\mathbb{Q} \subset E \subset L_f$ such that the extension $L_f \vert E$ has degree $2$, or there are exactly three fields satisfying those conditions.

I'm really stuck on this problem. I know that somewhere I should use the Fundamental Theory of Galois theory, but I don't know how.

Furtheremore, I know that since $f$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$, its Galois group must be $\mathbb{Z}_3$ or $S_3$. If it is the last one, I know that $S_3$ has exactly three subgroups of order two, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$ and $(2,3)$, and if it is $\mathbb{Z}_3$, there are no subgroups of order $2$, but I don't know how this two facts are related with the number of fields of degre $2$. Any help with this willbe highly appreciate, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of Galois theory? The Galois correspondance relates degrees of extensions with orders of subgroups...

Comment: @Crostul That's what I think I don't understand properly. So if I want to find an extension of degree $2$ I just need to find a subgroup of the Galois group of order $2$?

Comment: That's what the theorem says. It was easy, wasn't it?

Comment: @Crostul It was easy indeed. I was confused beacuase I thought that to find extensions of degree $2$ I needed to find subgroups of order $6/2 =3$. That was my mistake. Thanks for the clarifying it!

Comment: Degree of the intermediate field over the base field = index of the subgroup.

Comment: Degree of the splitting field over the intermediate field = order of the subgroup.

Comment: In your exercise, the latter is adressed, hence you search for groups order $2$.